# What's the meaning of "pass" here?

Tags: vocabulary

Actor Vin Diesel was talking about his new movie "Furious 7" in Jimmy Kimmel Live, an American late night talk show.

At 1:48 into this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf8WeWDYhiU), Diesel said:

> And they really did drop the cars. I mean, we did practical **pass**es so much.

The movie has a scene where each car was dropped out of an airplane and then was landed successfully with the help of a parachute attached to each of them. What Vin Diesel is saying here is that they didn't use CGI but that they actually dropped the cars to shoot the scene. In this context, what would "pass" mean?

Comment: Pass = Overtake perhaps

Comment: Isn't 'pass' here a noun and 'overtake' a verb?

Comment: As I listen to it that sentence is unintelligible.  It sounds like "we did a practical pass as so much".

Comment: @Hot Licks, does your transcription make sense?

Comment: No.  Like I said it's unintelligible.  (I kinda wonder if he meant to say "we did a practice pass", but I don't know what the following few sounds would be then.)

Comment: @listeneva The only context I had at the time was cars, so I thought he might have been using the verb "to pass" another car as a noun. So the number of (practical) passes was the number of times they practiced overtaking. Now that you've added the context of dropping cars from planes, I think this is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The term [practical effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_effect) refers to

> a special effect produced physically, without computer-generated imagery or other post production techniques.

When you *do* use computer-generated imagery, the computer might render it in multiple stages, perhaps using different techniques -- each of those is called a [rendering pass](http://3drender.com/light/compositing/index.html).

I haven't heard the term "practical pass" before, but it's not a great leap to assume that it means creating part of a scene with practical effects, rather than CGI.

Comment: That seems like it. Were you be able to hear exactly what Diesel said in the video?

Comment: @listeneva It sounds exactly like "we did a practical pass sss so much" to me -- it sounds more like he's just stammering at the ssss part than trying to say an actual word.   I'd suggest trying to say the phrase out loud; without deliberately pausing it's hard to say "pass so much" without it sounding like that.

Answer (score 0):

My take. It's one of the **magical feats** referred to in here:

> **pass** noun
>
> 6
>
> a :  a transference of objects by sleight of hand or other deceptive
>   means
>
> b :  a gesture or movement of the hands of a juggler or magician
>
> c :  a shifting of the position of the cards in card tricks
>
> d :  a moving of the hands over or along something :  manipulation
>
> 7 archaic :  a witty or ingenious sally or stroke
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary